# how to safety check a composite key before assigning it as a foreign key?

Tags: mysql

So normally when one wants to declare a foreign key on a populated table, they'll first make sure that the foreign table has all the values contained in the table where the foreign key is being created.

```
    select * from myschema.Orders
        where ProductID not in
            (select ProductID from myschema.Products);
```

Should any records be returned from the above query, then the DBA will first have to deal with those before setting a foreign key. But what if the `Products` table contained a composite foreign key? How would the above check be done if the Products table had both the fields `ProductID` and (For example) `BatchNumber` as a primary key?

This is assuming the `Orders` table also has both fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in that case.

Something like this:

```
select *
from myschema.Orders o
where not exists (
        select ProductID
        from myschema.Products p
        where o.ProductID = p.ProductID
            and o.BatchNumber = p.BatchNumber
        );
```